# Finding whether each element in matrix is reciprocal of it's transpose in 3d tensor

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy matrix of shape m * n * n, meaning I have m n*n square matrices. For each matrix, I must have elements present in such a way so that the transpose indexes are reciprocal of each other. If any occurrence or violation is detected, return False, otherwise, return True.

In the image the answer is true because we have four matrices of shape 3*3, and every element in the matrix is reciprocal of the transpose element.

This code is to be deployed, so I would expect that the process takes the least amount of time and maximum parallelism is achieved.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz7uC.png)

I don't know how to approach it. I tried ChatGPT, but it gave me possible worst results

Comment: Please include the example data, the code you tried, and desired results as text rather than a linked image.

Comment: Have you work out how to test this for one (n,n) array?  copy-n-paste the example.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that in your example your condition might not be fulfilled as you want to check if entries on transpose indices are exactly reciprocal to each other. But `0.11111111 * 9 != 1`. I assume the value 0.11111111 is 1/9 [but 1/9 cannot be exactly stored as a floating point number in base 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary).

Anyway, to check if one n x n array fulfills your requirement, you can multiply the array element-wise with its tranpose matrix and check if all elements in this matrix are 1:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0.25,4],[4,1,9], [0.25, 1/9, 1]])

b = np.multiply(a, a.T)

# check if any values in b are not 1
print(np.any(b != 1.0)
```

If you run into issues with the exact equality (as mentioned above) you might want to use [np.isclose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead.

For your m x n x n array you can simply loop over all m arrays. There might be a more efficent way but afaik, there is no direct way to apply functions to 2D-slices of a 3D-array:

```py
def check_reciprocal(mats: np.ndarray) -> bool:
   for mat in mats:
      if np.any(np.multiply(mat, mat.T) != 1.0):
         return False
   return True
```

To speed it up, one could potentially reshape the 2D-matrices into 1D-arrays and then use [np.apply_along_axis()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) or compile the function using numba.

Comment: Using `np.apply_along_axis` is neither necessary, nor sufficient to accelerate code. As stated in its own documentation, it is not meant for performance.  You can simply transpose the 2 last axis, and check `np.isclose(M*(M.transpose(0,2,1)),1).all()`

Comment: Nice solution. But where does the documentation for `apply_along_axis` says this? I know that the documentation for `vectorize` explicitly states that it is for convenience but could not find anything regarding that for `apply_along_axis`. It even states that it is faster than the equivalent loop implementation.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, I was thinking of `vectorize`. But sames, almost, goes for `apply_along_axis`. If what you pass as function to `apply_along_axis` is a ufunc, I guess it may be fast. Note sure. But well, just try it. Compare execution time of, say `np.sum(arr, axis=0)` and `np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 0, arr)` for a 1000×3 array. 200 `apply_along_axis` is 200 times slower on my machine. Also, anyway, I don't know how to apply it on this example (hence my simple `sum` example here), because it seems to work on 1D sub-arrays only.

Comment: So, indeed, `apply_along_axis` doc's doesn't say so. But practical experimentation shows that it is the same. It is faster than a for loop, sure. Everything is. Because the `for` loop itself is done in C, not in python. And if what is passed is a numpy func, the inner code of that func is also C, not python. But in between, you have 1000 python call's to that inner function.  But maybe you had a specific usage in mind, for which it is fast (again, the docs doesn't say it is slow, indeed; I only can't build a single example where it is not, but may be there are some, with ufuncs).

Comment: How would you answer the question with `apply_along_axis`? (with `vectorize`, I would `fv=np.vectorize(lambda A: np.isclose(A*A.T,1).all(), signature='(n,m)->()')`, and then call `fv(M).all()`. But with `apply_along_axis` I don't know how to apply a function of a matrix

Comment: Thx for the info. I do not know how to implement this with `apply_along_axis`, it was just an idea for further improvement (knowing that using `vectorize` would not speed anything up). Your solution using N-dimensional transpose is better imho.